# When I run this code, (print) function doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code the `print` function doesn’t work , so I tried to move it around and check if there is any mistake , but it doesn’t work at all.

```py
def is_substring(small,big):
    count=0

    for move in range(len(big)):

        if big[move:move+len(small)] == small:
            return True
            count+=1

    return False


    print(f"we found {count} similar words")


is_substring('hi','hi and Hello or hi')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.
What is your code expected to do? What does it print and what should it print?

Comment: This type of string formatting was introduced from python version 3.6. Make sure you have the latest version installed. Also return true after you increment the count var.

Comment: `print(f"we found {count} similar words")` is located after the `return` statement and is therefore unreachable.

Comment: As already pointed problem is that your `print` is unreachable. I want suggest you to consider using one of Python linters. For example when I used `pylint3` on your code it informed me that `W: 13, 4: Unreachable code (unreachable)` meaning that code at line `13` is unreachable (as well showing some other issues, but regarding style rather than matter - for example that you should use space after *,* and so on)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're `return`-ing before print is called.

`return 'something'`

will exit the function, passing `'something'` back to where the function call came from, so `return True` skips anything afterwards.

Try just checking the value of count after all the looping:

```
def is_substring(small,big):
    count=0    
    for move in range(len(big)):
        if big[move:move+len(small)] == small:
            count+=1

    print(f"we found {count} similar words")
    return count != 0

is_substring('hi','hi and Hello or hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem with `return` answered by @Tim already, you can streamline your code using [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Sum up ones for all `len(small)`-length substrings that are equal to `small` - using [sum( )](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) on a generator that delivers only those that fit your `small` text:

```
def count_substring(text,small):
        len_small = len(small)

        #  xt[i:i+len_small] == small  is a boolean, which evaluates to 1 if True else 0 
        return sum( text[i:i+len_small] == small for i in range(len(text)-len_small) )
```

text = ("For questions about Python programming that are specific to version 3+"
       " of the language. Use the more generic [python] tag if your question "
       "is not version-specific. Use the [python-2.x] tags for Python 2 questions.")

```
print(count_substring(text,"python"))
print(count_substring(text,"the"))
print(count_substring(text,"c#"))
```

Output:

```
2
3
0
```

This is a bit shorter due to built-ins and because I only check up to `range(len(text)-len_small` - using less iterations. The slices after that are shorter then `small` anyway. You can get the `is_substring(..)` part by comparing `count_substring(text,"c#") > 0`

(`text` taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)